# Git init is not able to update default branch to main branch instead of master branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On vscode, using `wsl` terminal, I was setting the global the default branch as `main` as shown below,

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

Now, inside my project folder, when I do `git init` and check `git status` the default branch is still `master`. What else I need to do to make the default branch as `main`?

Even `.gitconfig`, contains defaultBranch as main:

```
cat ~/.gitconfig

[init]
    defaultBranch = main
```

**Current git version:**

```
git version2.25.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Git has multiple levels of config: system, global, local.

If you want to quickly verify what happens in your local repo just`git config -e --local` or `git config --list` to see

Otherwise modify  the global `~/.gitconfig` yourself config and add/update section:

```
[init]
  defaultBranch = main
```

Comment: `git config --list` this show `defaultBranch = main`, but still when I do `git init`, I see `master` branch as default :|

Answer (score -2):

I tried to update the git version from  `git version2.25.1` to current latest version i.e., `git version 2.41.0`. After this my git configurations are getting correctly detected.

From [@RickN's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316310/rickn) comment,

*The defaultBranch option was introduced in Git 2.28, so your config file was detected without fault, just with an unsupported configuration option.*

Comment: The `defaultBranch` option was introduced in Git 2.28, so your config file was detected without fault, just with an unsupported configuration option.

Comment: Now got to know the exact reason. Thanks for clarifying. You can post this as answer, I will accept :)

Comment: Nah, its fine, you solved it yourself so just edit that in & self-accept your own answer (may take a little while until it gives you the option).